# Failed to add custom header to Request payload using OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to add multiple custom headers to every Request payload from my app so that a server could recognize request and ignore some of them that do not supply valid headers.

I tried to use https://square.github.io/okhttp/ to intercept my request with corresponding custom headers.

**Dendencies:**

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
```

**Code for adding custom client:**

```
  OkHttpClient HttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()

                                 .addHeader("header_name1","value1").build();
                                 .addHeader("header_name2","value2").build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }).build();
```

Then, I add Custom interceptor to retrofit like this:

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.BASE_URL)
                .client(defaultHttpClient) 
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

> When I try to log Request, I find that headers are not added to payload, to prove this I have tested my API in postman passing headers and it is working as expected.I guess I am doing it wrong but I have tried all accepted solutions with no success. Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are your using android 9 device and URL is the url http and not https?

Comment: No I am using android 4.4.2 API 19 and my API is hosted on heroku means URL is https.

Comment: @RajatBeck would that be the issue? if so how to solve it?

Comment: In Pie and above you need to use https otherwise android will not send your request , for using http you need to white list your url. you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: @RajatBeck, thanks for that info, I followed the provided link but it is not solving my actual problem for this time.

Comment: The code you wrote to add the headers cannot be right because it doesn't compile. You're calling `build()` 2 times. Also, when and how are you logging the request?